# Using Texcount Templates

Tags: templates, fp, texcount

Anybody have a `texcount` template they would share?

I noticed that the `texcount` documentation references an option `-template="template"`. I presume this is to enable adding some custom text surrounding the texcount output. My Google-fu has not yielded any examples of what such a template would look like.

I was hoping to combine this with something like `fp` to make a template that reports a more narrative style summary of my document, to include a calculation of word count according to the publication rules (e.g., text, headers and bibliography + 100 words per figure/table/float).

Comment: I just use a script and a custom `.cfg` file. In particular, the script updates the `.cfg` on the basis of comment lines in documents. Probably not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example could be

```
texcount.pl example.tex -template="Words: {hword} in headers,
   {word} in text, {oword} other places."
```

which should be all on one line.

An alternative way to specify this template is in the TeX document itself using the `%TC` instructions. Here's a more elaborate example of this:

```
%%% Template using new format (version 3 and on)
%TC:newtemplate
%TC:template Word count (text+headers+other):
%TC:template  {text}+{headerword}+{otherword} = {sum}\n
%TC:template Element count (head+float+inline+dsmath):
%TC:template  {header}+{float}+{inline}+{displaymath}\n
%TC:template Subcounts{SUB?: {sum}?SUB}
```

Note that `\n` indicates line shift which will have to specified explicitly.

You can also specify a template as well as other options in a separate options file, which may sometimes be convenient for big templates. For example, if you make a file with the contents

```
 # Use as sum count: text words + header words + other words
 -sum=1,1,1

 # Output template
 -template=
   \<ul class=count>\n
   \<li class=header>{title}</li>\n
   \<li>Word count: {sum}</li>\n
   \<li>Equations: {inline} inline, {ds} displayed</li>\n
   \{float?<li>Floats: {float}</li>\n?float}
   \{SUB?<li>Subcounts:</li><span class=subcount>\n
   \| <li>{sum} words in {title}</li>\n
   \|</span>\n?SUB}
   \{file?<li>Number of files in all: {file}</li>?file}\n
   \</ul>\n
```

you can include it using the `-opt=` option. This outputs the counts using HTML tags. The `SUB` section gives subcounts.

These examples, I hope, could make for starting points for experimenting.

Comment: This is **exactly** what I needed. Thank you @einar. I'm using (included in my Linux distro) v2.3, but this still ends up being much more simple than what I'd been trying to do.

Comment: Oh! ...and the `-sum=` option lets me weight counts without having to use `fp`, too. I get exactly what I need with `texcount -sum=1,1,0,0,100,1,100`.

Comment: @CWDillon: Nice to hear it was of use. To use names like `word` and `hword` instead of index 1 and 2 for text and header words, requires that you upgrade TeXcount to v3.0: this can be done either through the TeX package update or by downloading the texcount perl script and replacing the one you have. The `-sum=`option, sadly, does not recognise these names and instead uses the `1,1,...` format.