# Can I put a word count right into my LaTeX book?

Tags: counters, word-count

I want to say inside my book how many words it has. Are you aware of any packages that can help me with this?

Comment: This should be possible with the external `texcount` binary and some `\immediate\write18` black magic ;-)

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document).

Comment: The TeXcount FAQ gives some tips on how to [run word count from LaTeX](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#latexcall) and [include the count in the document](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#includecount). It is also possible to use [output templates](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239689/using-texcount-templates) to style the output, eg to produce LaTeX code for document inclusion.