# Remove all tables from document

Tags: tables, word-count

I need to do a wordcount of my thesis that excludes tables, but not their legends. I need to remove all of my tables, ideally with a command in the preamble. I am currently using Foxit reader's wordcount tool.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

        \begin{table}[h!]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{l l l l}
                \hline
                Foo & Bar \\ bar bar bar & Sum & Foo \\ \hline
                Foo & Bar & Sum & Foo \\
                Foo & Bar & Sum & Foo \\
                Foo & Bar & Sum & Foo  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption[Contexts]{Le Table}
            \label{table:tisch}
        \end{table} 

The table is Table \ref{table:tisch}.
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just an idea: How about using the comment package and redefining the `tabular` environment to act as a `comment` environment?

Comment: Yes that works. If you would like to submit this as answer I will accept it, otherwise I will answer my own question incorporating your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for asking! But please add an answer yourself, I would have to create an example first and you seem to already have the code.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the comments `tabular` environments are now ignored through redefinition of this command with the `comment` package. This is based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50912/74744) answer.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{tabular}
\let\endtabular\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l l l l}
      \hline
      Foo & Bar \\ bar bar bar & Sum & Foo \\ \hline
      Foo & Bar & Sum & Foo \\
      Foo & Bar & Sum & Foo \\
      Foo & Bar & Sum & Foo  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption[Contexts]{Le Table}
    \label{table:tisch}
\end{table}
The table is Table \ref{table:tisch}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use [TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/index.html), which should most likely come along with your TeX installation, which defaults to ignoring tables but counting their captions. By default, headlines, regular text, and caption texts are counted separately, but this [can be modified](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#newmacro) if desired.

It is possible to call TeXcount from the TeX/LaTeX document, and include the word count: see [details in the FAQ](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#includecount), or StackExchanges questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324283/can-i-put-a-word-count-right-into-my-latex-book#comment792078_324283).